# What's wrong with these macro parameters?

Tags: sas, sas-macro

I have the following simplified version of a piece of code that I am working on:

```
%macro test(var);

%if &var = 'Sub Prime' %then %do;
%let var2 = 'Sub_Prime';
%put &var2;
%end;
%mend;

%test(Sub%str( )Prime);
```

Basically the point of this is that if var = 'Sub Prime' that var2 should = 'Sub_Prime'. It appears though that var does not equal 'Sub Prime'. Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Macro variables do not use quotations.

```
%macro test(var);

%if &var = %str(Sub Prime) %then %do;
  %let var2 = Sub_Prime;
  %put &=var2;
%end;
%mend;

%test(Sub%str( )Prime);
```

You'd be better off using `%str` around the whole thing, though, rather than inserting the %str in just the space.

```
%test(%str(Sub Prime));
```

Comment: that worked great, thanks. i cant accept your answer for another 9 minutes though, but thanks.

Comment: @gdogg371 A great way to test macros when you are not getting expected results is to print out the expression to the log.  Ie. take this bit of code from your original question `&var = 'Sub Prime'` and just do a `%put` in front of it.  `%put &var = 'Sub Prime';`.  Pretty quickly you will realise that the string without the quotes is not equal to the string with the quotes.

Comment: It looks to me like it shouldn't be necessary to use %str() here at all. Is it?  The only character it could be masking is a blank, but why would that need to be masked?  (I'm away from SAS, so can't try it. )

Comment: @Quentin Probably not.  I included it because OP included it and I don't know their specific needs, but I think you're right.